# Checking validity types error while running next build

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js, material-ui

I'm getting the following error while running next build.

[image: error]

I already tried to update to ES6, change the module to commonJs, downgrade the webpack to version 4 and nothing changed.
The only thing that allowed me to get around this problem was enable the ignoreBuildErrors in next.config.js.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What `@mui/material` version are you using?
What version of NextJS are you using?
How are you importing the exported values from `@mui/material/ClickAwayListener?`

Comment: @mui/material version ^5.14.8, next 11.0.1, and I haven't directly imported.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong couldn't the error be caused by the extra "," after the ClickAwayListenerProps.

Comment: No, TS just ignores the final comma, the problem is that it isn't recognizing an explicit export of a TS type.